# Spring Integration JDBC Batch Insert

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a requirement to insert a list of POJO to be inserted into the database. I have a stored procedure which performs one insert at a time. In the current implementation, I have a splitter that splits on the POJO and passes that payload to the stored proc outbound gateway to call my stored procedure.

In a real time scenario my list size could be as big as 500K. So Is there a way for a better implementation? Is there a way to perform a batch insert in SI flow?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what your measurement criterion is, but here are a few suggestions: (1) Don't INSERT one at a time; batch requests to cut down on network traffic, (2) Chunk the list into smaller pieces that you commit as a unit of work so you don't create a huge rollback segment, (3) See if Java 8 parallel streams make it go faster.

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?  You'll probably have to get pretty low-level if you're inserting 500K in real-time.  For example, MySQL has a LOAD INTO call that takes an input stream which is much faster than the standard batch insert.

Comment: Right now, Spring Integration does not support this feature. There is feature request for it - https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3364.
So, I use self-written outbound channel adapter for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote mentioned custom outbound channel adapter, which uses spring-jdbc batch ability:

```
public class ArrayListSqlBatchOBCA {

  private final static Logger           log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArrayListSqlBatchOBCA.class);
  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate    template;
  private String                        sql;

  public void process(Message<? extends ArrayList<?>> message) throws Exception {

    try {
          ArrayList<?> list = (ArrayList<?>) message.getPayload();

          SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs = new SqlParameterSource[list.size()];
          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
              batchArgs[i] = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(list.get(i));
          }

          template.batchUpdate(sql, batchArgs);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Exception while processing message", e);
          throw e;
      }
   }
}
```

This is how I use it (XML config):

```
  <channel id="cc"/>
  <outbound-channel-adapter channel="cc" method="process">
      <beans:bean class="mypackage.ArrayListSqlBatchOBCA">
          <beans:property name="template" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
          <beans:property name="sql" 
             value="INSERT INTO test (field1,field2,field3)  
                    VALUES (:f1,:f2,:f3)"/>
  </beans:bean>
  </outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Further, I added `?reWriteBatchedInserts=true` to jdbc url of my datasource (I use postgres JDBC driver).

[Documentation about the option](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html):

reWriteBatchedInserts - Enable optimization to rewrite and collapse compatible INSERT statements that are batched. If enabled, pgjdbc rewrites batch of `insert into ... values(?, ?)` into `insert into ... values(?, ?), (?, ?), ...`

This way, using a small custom code, I insert multiple rows at once from input collection.